# maven build with remote pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, maven

I would like to know weather there is a way/plugin to build a project with maven using a remote pom.xml(http://host:port/pom.xml) with out a pom.xml file in the directory where I run "mvn install".

I need this as I want to effect maven dependencies of multiple clients by making changes to one remote file hosted at (http://host:port/pom.xml).

Comment: It would be great if maven would have, like the parameter -f, another parameter like '-urlf=http://my_mvn_host/my_repository/my-pom.xml'

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do this. Generally, if you are doing development with multiple developers, you should be using source control. For example, if you are using subversion, you would just make changes to the pom, commit, and the other developers can update.

Answer (score 0):

Of course using a version control is absolutely necessary...It would quite helpfull to use a Maven Repository Manager to interchange the artifacts with each other simply by deploying the artifacts to a central Repository Manager in your company and furthermore it will increase the build time.

Comment: Okay, how can we tell the child pom that you fetch all of your configuration and dependency from that pom (present in the git or some other VCS).

Comment: Can you be more concrete? You inherit the configuration (what ever you mean by that) better using dependencyManagement/pluginManagement?

Comment: By inherit the configuration i mean, I have a team of 9-10 developers, and i want them to give them a pom template, that they only add the related project dependency. not the common dependency like junit, web etc. So how their pom inherit my master pom remotely. Now in the future if I change my one of the dependency, all the pom's which is connected to that master pom consumes that changes. If possible then plz provide some practicle code example.

Comment: Moreover I put my master pom to a private github repository, and how the child pom find that master pom.

Comment: First only use pluginManagement to define the plugins (with default configurations) with the appropriate version. The dependencies should be done via a BOM (if you have a lot of deps in common)... If you change deps you have to release that bom (change the version) which will be then changed in to the project who are consuming it...This means the parent pom as well as the BOM are separate project (git repos) which are build/released separately.

Comment: Example: Parent https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp consumer of the parent: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension (deps are defined here on their own)...but you can create a BOM and release/import that as well.

Comment: are you put the parent pom in nexus remote repository

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: I just saw your parent pom, it has alot of detail which I as a beginner didn't understand, can you have a simple parent and child pom example. parent in nexus and child in local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can try mapping the remote location (possibly a network share or an FTP location) to a local drive, and then executing the maven command in your console for the mapped location. It should work.

Else, you can distribute the `pom.xml` file via an email and ask the users to use it as their project file.

The other option is to use a Version Control System (VCS) such as Mercurial and keeping your `pom.xml` stored in the repository and make it accessible for the users to checkout. So far, this is the best way to make sure everyone is using the same file.